# What's the meaning of "if not as"?

Tags: meaning

> Equally so **if not as** potentially costly are headlines where...

I found this sentence [on the Internet](https://books.google.com/books?id=ztI388MH1qQC&pg=PA211&dq=%22Equally%20so%20if%20not%20as%20potentially%20costly%20are%20headlines%20where%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv-J_EwbjdAhUH8YMKHQN8BxQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Equally%20so%20if%20not%20as%20potentially%20costly%20are%20headlines%20where%22&f=false) but was unable to understand it, especially the 'if not as' part. Does it mean 'costly but in a lesser manner' or 'at least as costly as this'? Thanks.

Comment: If it is possible for you, please write the rest of the sentence in order to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it means:

> Equally *[something]* but in a less costly manner.

---

Let me explain.

We can't know what the *something* is because we are missing the context of previous information.

For the sake of an explanation, I'll make up a previous sentence:

> Any shortage in our widget supply is devastating to our company.

Also, there needs to be a conclusion to the example sentence you provided. I will make that up too:

> . . . are headlines where our failures are made public.

Now, we have some context for the phrase in question.

---

Let me restate everything—and also add some commas around what I believe to be nonessential information your example sentence:

> Any shortage in our widget supply is devastating to our company. Equally so, **if not as** potentially costly, are headlines where our failures are made public.

This can now be analyzed as follows:

- Any widget shortage is *devastating*.
- Such widget shortages are *devastating* in terms of cost.
- Equally *devastating* is bad publicity from headlines.
- This bad publicity is *devastating* in terms of reputation.

---

Returning to the text you actually provided:

> Equally so **if not as** potentially costly are headlines where...

And to your question:

> Does it mean 'costly but in a lesser manner' or 'at least as costly as this'? Thanks.

---

Since there is no context along the lines that I made up, it's not possible to know exactly what your fragment is referencing.

In it, *equally so* is referring to *something*—but we don't know *what*.

Assuming my hypothetical situation, we could rephrase it as:

> Equally *devastating* if not as potentially costly are headlines where . . .

*If* that were true, then the answer to your question would be that it means:

> Equally devastating but in a less costly manner.

---

So, the actual answer to your question, as much as one can be given from what has been provided, is that it means:

> Equally *[something]* but in a less costly manner.

Comment: I think you shouldn't gloss over the "potentially" in "potentially less costly". It doesn't mean "in a less costly manner" It means (for example) that the headlines where equally as effective, but carried **less risk** of the paper losing money/reputation/customers because of them. (It's hard to say exactly what the "cost" is without more context.) Less risk of incurring a cost is not the same thing as less costly.

Comment: @ColleenV You're right. But if I start to explain the nuances of both the meaning of *costly* and *potential*, the answer would end up being at least twice as long as it is now. (*Cost* can mean many things, none of which are made clear in the short fragment available.) Also, I don't necessarily agree that *potential* means *risk* here. Although, without the missing broader context, I can't say either way.

Comment: Well the good news is that we don’t charge extra for long answers. All words cost the same as the first one you wrote ;) If you look at the Google Books  link I added to the question, it might help.